# Xamarin Forms EntryCell added to an existing TableView in c# cannot be accssed in CustomViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm new to Xamarin Forms. I've added an EntryCell to an existing TableSection of a TableView in c#. I'm trying to access the EntryCell entered value in CustomViewModel, but i'm not able to access it from my customviewmodel.

**TabbedPage1**

```
        <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:FamTreeApp.Behaviors" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FamTreeApp.Views"
                x:Class="FamTreeApp.Views.TabbedPage1">
        <TabbedPage.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:TabbedPageNavigationBehavior />
        </TabbedPage.Behaviors>
        <TabbedPage.Children>
            <local:Tab1 Title ="Tab1" class="material-icons" Icon ="user.png" />
            <local:Tab2 Title="Tab2" class="material-icons" Icon ="sharp_group_add_black_18.png" />

        </TabbedPage.Children>
    </TabbedPage>
```

**Tab1.xaml**

```
        <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="FamTreeApp.Views.Tab1">
        <TableView x:Name="SpouseTable" Intent="Form">
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection x:Name="SpouseTS" Title="Parents">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="SpouseStack">

                            <Button Text="Submit" Clicked="OnSubmit"></Button>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
        </TableView>

    </ContentPage>
```

**Tab1.xaml.cs**

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

    namespace FamTreeApp.Views
    {
        [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class Tab1 : ContentPage
        {

            public Tab1()
            {
      
                InitializeComponent();
         
            }

            private void OnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                EntryCell entInput = new EntryCell
                {
                    Placeholder = "Name" 
                };
                string txt = "{Binding Name}";
                entInput.SetBinding(EntryCell.TextProperty, txt);
                SpouseTS.Add(entInput);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Tab2.xaml**

```
ontentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="FamTreeApp.Views.Tab2">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

**Tab2.xaml.cs**

```
        public partial class Tab2 : ContentPage
    {
        public Tab2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
            public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INavigationAware
        {
            private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

            public ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService)
            {
                this.navigationService = navigationService;
            }

            private string title;
            public string Title
            {
                get => this.title;
                set => SetProperty(ref this.title, value);
            }

            public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters) { }

            public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters) { }

            public virtual void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters) { }

           }
```

**TabbedPageNavigationBehavior**

```
            using Prism.Behaviors;
        using Prism.Common;
        using Prism.Navigation;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Text;
        using Xamarin.Forms;

        namespace FamTreeApp.Behaviors
        {

                public class TabbedPageNavigationBehavior : BehaviorBase<TabbedPage>
                {
                    private Page CurrentPage;

                    protected override void OnAttachedTo(TabbedPage bindable)
                    {
                        bindable.CurrentPageChanged += this.OnCurrentPageChanged;
                        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
                    }

                    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(TabbedPage bindable)
                    {
                        bindable.CurrentPageChanged -= this.OnCurrentPageChanged;
                        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
                    }

                    private void OnCurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        var newPage = this.AssociatedObject.CurrentPage;

                        if (this.CurrentPage != null)
                        {
                            var parameters = new NavigationParameters();
                            PageUtilities.OnNavigatedFrom(this.CurrentPage, parameters);
                            PageUtilities.OnNavigatedTo(newPage, parameters);
                        }

                        this.CurrentPage = newPage;
                    }
                }

        }
```

**Tab1Model.cs**

```
        using Prism;
    using Prism.Navigation;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using Prism.Navigation.TabbedPages;
    using FamTreeApp.Models;
    using FamTreeApp.Views;

    namespace FamTreeApp.ViewModels
    {
        public class Tab1Model : ViewModelBase
        {
            public Tab1Model(INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(navigationService)
            {
                this.Title = nameof(Tab1);

            }


            public override void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
            {
                base.OnNavigatedFrom(parameters);
     
                  **parameters.Add(nameof(this.Name), this.Name);**

            }

        }
    }
```

**Tab2Model.cs**

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    //using FamTreeApp.ViewModels.FamTreeApp.Views;
    using Prism;
    using Prism.Navigation;
    //using FamTreeApp.ViewModels.FamTreeApp.Models;

    namespace FamTreeApp.ViewModels
    {
        namespace FamTreeApp.ViewModels
        {
            public class Tab2Models : ViewModelBase

            {

               private string name;
        
                public Tab2Models(INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(navigationService)
                {
                    //this.Title = nameof(Tab2);

                }

   
                public override void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
                {
                    base.OnNavigatedFrom(parameters);
          
                }

            }


        }

    }
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
        using Prism;
    using Prism.Ioc;
    using FamTreeApp.ViewModels;
    using FamTreeApp.Views;
    using Xamarin.Essentials.Interfaces;
    using Xamarin.Essentials.Implementation;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Prism.DryIoc;
    using Prism.Navigation;

    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

    namespace FamTreeApp
    {
        public partial class App : PrismApplication
        {
            public App() : this(null) { }

            public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

            protected override async void OnInitialized()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(TabbedPage1));

            }

            protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
            {
                containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<TabbedPage1>();
                containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Tab1, Tab1Model>();
                containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Tab2, Tab2Models>();

 
            }
        }

    }
```

How do I access the value of the EntryCell(created on the click of submit button) in its ViewModel - Tab1Models? Here I've used Prism, how can I accessed the value of the newly created EntryCell its custom ViewModel with or without Prism?

Comment: first, please post **relevant** code.  There is about 5x too much included here and that makes it very difficult to wade through.  Second, when using the `SetBinding` method you just provide the binding path, "Name" not "{Binding Name}".  Third, I don't see a "Name" property on your VM so I'm not sure what you're trying to bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you are not using `SetBinding` correctly

```
        private void OnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EntryCell entInput = new EntryCell
            {
                Placeholder = "Name" 
            };
            
            // bind to a property "Name"
            entInput.SetBinding(EntryCell.TextProperty, "Name");
            SpouseTS.Add(entInput);
        }
```

then in your VM you need a `Name` property

```
public class Tab1Model : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Tab1Model(INavigationService navigationService)
        : base(navigationService)
        {
            this.Title = nameof(Tab1);

        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(parameters);
 
            parameters.Add(nameof(this.Name), this.Name);
        }
    }
```

note that I am assuming you have your `BindingContext` set correctly or that Prism is doing it for you - I'm not familiar with how Prism handles that

Comment: Thank you so much.... I've added the properties in the my real mini project but I've use "Binding" in SetBinding like this             string txt = "{Binding Name}";
            entInput.SetBinding(EntryCell.TextProperty, txt), this is the mistake. Thank you Jason

Comment: I want to pass the data (from both the Tab1 and Tab2 which I get in Model2's OnNavigatedTo) on the click of submit button of Tab2.xaml.cs, how can i do this?

Comment: I'd use the same instance of the VM for both tabs

Comment: are you saying single ViewModel for all tabs using prism or without prism? I'm not able access the bindingcontext without the new keyword on Submit button click of xaml.cs of Tab2

Comment: again, I really don't know anything about Prism.  That is just generally how I'd solve it.  You should probably ask a new question specifically focused on this problem

Comment: okay, thank you Jason... I've already asked this question(without the prism) but I never got the answer on how to access the values of the viewmodel without creating an instance in LastTab.xaml.cs's Submit Button Clicked Instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64477352/xamarin-forms-with-tabbed-pages-having-data-form-entry-page-in-each-tabbed-page

Comment: the question you posted on 10/22?  I made the **same suggestion** there - use a common VM across pages, and another user suggested using a Singleton.  Both are valid approaches

Comment: yes....it was long time back....i posted this question.... but I'm getting null values in the tabpage.xaml.cs even after I entered all the values in all my tabs. Then I saw the prism option.